# Volume / Surface of a Paraboloid through Integration

Tags: integration, volume, surface-integrals, parametrization, jacobian

Given is a Paraboloid delimited as following: 
$$z_1 = a(x^2 + y^2),\ z_2 = h  $$

That's my try for the Volume computation:

First I find the radius of the circle resulting from the intersection between $z_1$ and $z_2$ :

$ z = a(x^2 + y^2) = h \\ \frac{h}{a} = x^2 + y^2   $

so that means that the radius is $  \sqrt{ \frac{h}{a}}$.

Setting up the triple integral:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{ \frac{h}{a}}} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d \theta \int_h^{a(x^2 + y^2)} dz \cdot 1$$

Now the change of variables:

$ x = r cos \theta \ \  y =  r sin \theta$ , where the Jacobian $J = r$.

The integral would then look like this:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{ \frac{h}{a}}} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d \theta \int_h^{ar^2} dz  \cdot r = - \frac{1}{2} \pi \frac{h^2}{a}$$
The negative sign, I assume, is due to fact that at the first integration I integrated from $h$ to $ar^2$ and the other way around.

Is that correct?

Now, how do I compute the surface of the paraboloid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct set up for the volume in cylindrical coordinates should be

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d \theta \int_0^h \, dz   \int_0^{\sqrt{ \frac{z}{a}}}r \,dr $$

For the surface let use

$$S=2\pi \int_0^h f(z)\sqrt{1+[f’(z)]^2}\,dz$$

with $$f(z)=\sqrt{ \frac{z}{a}}$$

Comment: why is the lower bound $0$ at the $dz$ integral ??

Comment: Maybe I didn’t get what are the limits for $z$. We need an equation for the paraboloid that is $z=a(x^2+y^2)$ and 2 limits for z. I’ve assumed z=0 and z=h.

Comment: I thought the lower bound would actually be the function $z$ itself. By the way why did you substitute $h$ with $h$ ??

Comment: You need to specify the interval of variation according to cylindrical coordinates, take a look to the original problem to see how those limits are specified.

Comment: you mean the one I set up before the change of variables?

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is to find the volume between the paraboloid $z=a(x^2+y^2)$ and the plane $z=h$. The set up I’ve given is for that volume.

Comment: Ah ok maybe now I get the meaning of your set up! It is almost correct too but you need to reverse the limits for the last integral in order to obtain a positive volume!

Comment: yes that's correct, could you please specify the parametrisation you applied ?

Comment: ok then, if mine is correct you've got to explain the difference between mine and yours eheh

Comment: We have made two different but correct choices. You have considered the variation of r first and the z between the paraboloid and z=h. I have considered first a variation of z and the r as a function of z.

Comment: ok, perfect thanks, by changing the order of the last integral you mean the right most integral right?

Comment: yes since the paraboloid is downvand the plane z=h is up

Comment: what if I define $\vec{x} = \{ rcos\theta, rsin\theta, ar^2 \} $and then compute the surface like this: $\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{h} dr \left| \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \times   \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \right|$ ? would that work?

Comment: @Leroy Yes of course, you can try both methods and compare. For the one I gave refer also to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution